# How to initialize file-based data model in XAML page constructor

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

Given the fact that you can only use the **await** keyword inside a method marked async, what is the way to initialize a file-based data model from the constructor?  Still plan to set the DataContext in the OnNavigatedTo() method.

Previously, I would have simply said

> MyDataModel d = new MyDataModel();

and the constructor for MyDataModel would do the file I/O.

So far, all I've been able to figure out is that I can use a DispatchTimer in the constructor to fire off an event handler which is marked async and do the file I/O from there.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the DataModel as a parameter in the Navigate method, and cast it back in the OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e) from the e.Parameter.

-or-

You could try an IOC container, I've used [Ninject](http://www.ninject.org/), but not sure if it works with Metro apps yet.  [MVVM Light](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/) has a simple IOC conatiner as well.

Comment: Well... AFAIK, I can't pass the DataModel as a parameter to the OnNavigate method for the first page...that's invoked by the system, no?

Comment: Looks in App.cs, the first page is navigated to from there.

Comment: Agreed but it has the same problem.  There doesn't appear to be any way to invoke async File I/O in a class constructor.  Thus, my existing/working solution of having the constructor fire off a one-time timer event in order to get into an async method so I can 'await' on the I/O code seems to be the only option.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly (based on your comments on Michael's answer). You are having a hard time `await`ing an async operation in the constructor. Constructors can not be async, and thus you can not await any asyn method there. However, there is a simple work around; you can refactor all the async operations in the constructor and add them into an async Method but without awaiting it. In the example bellow, you can call `LoadFileAsync` from the constructor.

```
class MyDataModel
{
  public MyDataModel()
  {
      LoadFileAsync(); 
  }
  public async void LoadFileAsync()
  {
     // do async operations here 
     var file = await FooAsync(); 
  }
}
```

Doing this would ultimately allow you to set your data model from the constructor of the page, or from `onNavigateTo`

Answer (score 0):

Bottom line that I discovered is that it is essentially not possible to do file I/O with "apparent synchronous" behavior in an object constructor.

Thus, in my Win8 app, I had the choice to instantiate the data model before navigating to the first page (not really a good idea if that involves file I/O) or simply live with the "loosey goosey" visual experience such that my first page appears and then, after the data is loaded and the DataContext is updated with the actual data model, the data "flys in" when it's ready.

Given that apps are supposed to launch in < 5 seconds (and if possible much, much less than that), I chose the "loosey goosey" approach.